# Myrrix: What will happen now that it is part of Cloudera?

Tags: cloudera, myrrix

Myrrix was recently purchased by Cloudera. Will Myrrix become part of the Cloudera platform? Is there any estimate for when that will occur? Will there be a charge for the use of Myrrix in the future?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about unpublished intentions of a commercial organisation.


Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is off topic for SO, and better asked at https://getsatisfaction.com/myrrix)

The current Myrrix code base is end-of-lifed and will be unsupported after December 31, 2013.

Internally we are building a newer project from the code base, however. It may be open-sourced quite soon in fact, but I do not want to commit to anything.

Watch https://getsatisfaction.com/myrrix or the Myrrix mailing list for news.

PS the successor is Oryx and was released last October.

https://github.com/cloudera/oryx